# R : detect pattern at end of subject sequence

Tags: r, pattern-matching

I try to detect a pattern at the end of a DNA sequence. But I need to handle cases where the pattern can go beyond the end of the sequence.

Example

```
pattern  : AATTGGCC
subject1 : AAAAAAATTGGCCATGCACAA
subject2 : ATGGGTGTAGTAATTG
```

So here subject2 has the pattern at the end of the sequence
Results :

```
subject1 : AAAAAAATTGGCCATGCACAA
                AATTGGCC
  start : 6
  end   : 13 

subject2 : ATGGGTGTAGTAATTG
                      AATTGGCC
  start : 12
  end   : 16
```

My final goal will be to remove everything that is after the pattern (including the pattern).

My first idea was to use `matchPattern` function from Biostrings package to check for the pattern. If not detected to gradually trim the pattern from the right and reperform a matchpattern such as :

```
pattern <- "AATTGGCC" 
subject <- "ATGGGTGTAGTAATTG"
i <- nchar(pattern)
m <- matchPattern(pattern=pattern,subject)
while(length(m)==0 && i>0){
  i <- i-1
  p <- substring(pattern,1,i)
  m <- matchPattern(pattern=p,subject)
}
```

results :

```
    start end width
[1]    12  16     5 [AATTG]
```

But I need to do that one hundred of thousands of sequences and maybe it's not the most optimized way ...

Thanks

#### EDIT :

It should now work. If multiple patterns are in the subject sequence it cuts the sequence at the position of the first pattern

```
trimRead <- function(pattern,subject){
  require(Biostrings)
  i <- nchar(pattern)
  m <- matchPattern(pattern=pattern,subject)
  while(length(m)==0 && i>1){
    i <- i-1
    p <- substring(pattern,1,i)
    subject.sub <- substring(subject,first = nchar(subject)-nchar(p)+1) 
    m <- matchPattern(pattern=p,subject.sub)
  }
  if(length(m)>0){
    s <- nchar(subject)-nchar(subject(m)) + start(m)[1]
    return(substring(subject,first=1,last=(s-1)))
  }else{
    return(subject)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `Biostrings::pairwiseAlignment`, with local (Smith-Waterman) alignment:

```
require(Biostrings);
pattern <- "AATTGGCC";
subject <- "ATGGGTGTAGTAATTG";
m <- pairwiseAlignment(pattern = pattern, subject = subject, type = "local");
Views(m);
#  Views on a 16-letter BString subject
#subject: ATGGGTGTAGTAATTG
#views:
#    start end width
#[1]    12  16     5 [AATTG]
```

You can also get the start/end positions of the partial match (in `subject` coordinates) directly:

```
start(subject(m));
#[1] 12
end(subject(m));
#[1] 16
```

No need for manual trimming, that's the whole purpose of the [Smith-Waterman algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Waterman_algorithm).

Comment: This approach leads to wrong results when a subtring of the pattern is in the middle of the subject sequence. Example : `pattern <- "AATTGGCC" and `sequence <- "ATAAGGGACGCGAGACGCAATTGGAAAAA". It gives me 19 as a start. But only AATTGG if mapping. The two last "CC" are not matching.

Comment: @NicolasRosewick Yes of course, that's as expected. I'm curious. What *do* you expect to happen in your example from the comments?

Comment: The last `CC`s are *not* templated. Therefore, local alignment will only match `AATTGG` to `subject`. You *can* enforce alignment with mismatches by using `m <- pairwiseAlignment(pattern = pattern, subject = sequence, type = "global-local")`, where `type = "global-local"` ensures that the *whole* `pattern` is aligned to a *partial* `sequence`. See `?pairwiseAlignment` for details.

Comment: @NicolasRosewick A comment on your edit. I interpret your problem in the context of local (Smith-Waterman) sequence alignment, which is a standard problem in Bioinformatics (see also Blast); it's relevant in the context of motif search, gene identification, and any sequence similarity analyses. I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but trimming reads and then partially matching subsequences seems like reinventing the wheel to me. The SW algorithm has been optimised for exactly this task.